# Trouble with older style XML using node selection methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am having trouble parsing an older style XML document that uses a schema which is located in computer source files.

Here is part of the XML File.  I am trying to parse some of the data in each BuildingInfo:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Civ4BuildingInfos xmlns="x-schema:../Schema/C2C_CIV4BuildingsSchema.xml">
    <BuildingInfos>
        <BuildingInfo>
            <Type>BUILDING_3D_BODY_ATLAS</Type>
            <Description>TXT_KEY_BUILDING_3D_BODY_ATLAS</Description>
            <Civilopedia>TXT_KEY_BUILDING_3D_BODY_ATLAS_PEDIA</Civilopedia>
            <Strategy>TXT_KEY_BUILDING_3D_BODY_ATLAS_STRATEGY</Strategy>
            <Advisor>ADVISOR_SCIENCE</Advisor>
            <ArtDefineTag>ART_DEF_BUILDING_3D_BODY_ATLAS</ArtDefineTag>
            <MapCategoryTypes>
                <MapCategoryType>MAPCATEGORY_EARTH</MapCategoryType>
            </MapCategoryTypes>
            <PrereqTech>TECH_BIOMATHMATICS</PrereqTech>
            <iPrereqPopulation>13</iPrereqPopulation>
            <bPrereqPower>1</bPrereqPower>
            <Bonus>BONUS_COMPUTERS</Bonus>
            <PrereqInCityBuildings>
                <BuildingType>BUILDING_SYSTEMS_BIOLOGY_SIMULATOR</BuildingType>
                <BuildingType>BUILDING_MEDICAL_DATABASE_GOOD</BuildingType>
            </PrereqInCityBuildings>
            <iCost>2305</iCost>
            <iHealth>2</iHealth>
            <CommerceChanges>
                <iCommerce>-15</iCommerce>
                <iCommerce>5</iCommerce>
            </CommerceChanges>
            <SpecialistCounts>
                <SpecialistCount>
                    <SpecialistType>SPECIALIST_DOCTOR</SpecialistType>
                    <iSpecialistCount>1</iSpecialistCount>
                </SpecialistCount>
            </SpecialistCounts>
            <iHurryCostModifier>100</iHurryCostModifier>
            <PropertyManipulators>
                <PropertySource>
                    <PropertySourceType>PROPERTYSOURCE_CONSTANT</PropertySourceType>
                    <PropertyType>PROPERTY_EDUCATION</PropertyType>
                    <iAmountPerTurn>5</iAmountPerTurn>
                </PropertySource>
                <PropertySource>
                    <PropertySourceType>PROPERTYSOURCE_CONSTANT</PropertySourceType>
                    <PropertyType>PROPERTY_DISEASE</PropertyType>
                    <iAmountPerTurn>-15</iAmountPerTurn>
                </PropertySource>
            </PropertyManipulators>
            <iAIWeight>1</iAIWeight>
        </BuildingInfo>
```

At first I tried something like this:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(filename);
parentNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/Civ4BuildingInfos/BuildingInfos"); // returns null
XmlNodeList buildings = parentNode.SelectNodes("BuildingInfo"); // doesn't work either
```

After searching around to try and figure out why that didn't work, I learned I should use a namespace manager when a namespace is used.  So here is my new code that still doesn't work.  I am guessing the problem is that the reference is a file... not a URI/URL.  Or is it that the namespace includes a schema???  Not sure how to get this to work.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(filename);
XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("c2c", pathToFileOnComputer)
parentNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/c2c:Civ4BuildingInfos/BuildingInfos", nsManager); // still returns null
XmlNodeList buildings = parentNode.SelectNodes("c2c:BuildingInfo", nsManager); // still doesn't work either
```

Comment: you can try using linq-to-xml, XELement. You can easily walk any number of nodes this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use namespace exactly the same like in xml file

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(filename);
XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("c2c", "x-schema:../Schema/C2C_CIV4BuildingsSchema.xml");
var parentNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/c2c:Civ4BuildingInfos/c2c:BuildingInfos", nsManager); // still returns null
XmlNodeList buildings = parentNode.SelectNodes("c2c:BuildingInfo", nsManager);
```